# php mailer not working with attachment

Tags: php, phpmailer

in my php page i am sending mail from form. it's sending well but not sending with attachment. here's the code...

```
<form action="career.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal companyInquiry">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="margin: 10px; display:none;" id="errorLabel"></div>
                        <?php
                            if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' style='margin: 10px;' id='errorLabel'>";
                                    foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $err) echo "<p><b>$err</b></p>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                unset($_SESSION['error']);
                            }
                            if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
                                echo "<div class='alert alert-success' style='margin: 10px;' id='errorLabel'><p><b>".$_SESSION['message']."</b></p></div>";
                                unset($_SESSION['message']);
                            }
                        ?>
                        <p style="padding: 0px 10px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:#6E0C0B; font-size:16px;">
                            We Have Current Openings For.
                        </p>
                        <p style="padding: 0px 10px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; ">
                            Experienced Graphics designer(2 to 3 year).
                        </p>
                        <p style="padding: 0px 10px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; ">
                            Experienced PHP developer(2 to 3 year).
                        </p>
                        <p style="padding: 0px 10px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; ">
                            Interested Candidate, Please fill below form with fresh resume.
                        </p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fullName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['fullName'];?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="userEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['userEmail'];?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="userContact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact No</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="text" name="userContact" id="userContact" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['values'])) echo $_SESSION['values']['userContact'];?>" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="app_for" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Applied For</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <select name="app_for" id="app_for">
                                    <option value="Graphics designer">Graphics designer</option>
                                    <option value="PHP developer">PHP developer</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="you" class="col-sm-2 control-label">About You</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <textarea name="you" id="you" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter About You" style="border-radius:0"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="cv" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your CV</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="file" name="cv" id="cv">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <p style="text-align:left;">
                                    Only .xls,.xlsx,.pdf and .PDF extentions are allowed.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="send">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $_GET['com_id']; ?>" />
                    </form>
```

and my career.php file is.

```
<?php include_once("../../init.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    require_once(CONNECT);
    require_once('../../public/includes/mailer/config/class.phpmailer.php');
    $inc = -1;
    if($_POST['fullName'] == '') {
        $inc++;$_SESSION['error'][$inc] = "FULL NAME IS REQUIRED";
    }
    if($_POST['userEmail'] == '') {
        $inc++;$_SESSION['error'][$inc] = "EMAIL IS REQUIRED";
    }
    if($_POST['userContact'] == '') {
        $inc++;$_SESSION['error'][$inc] = "CONTACT NO IS REQUIRED";
    }
    if($_POST['userEmail'] != '' && $_POST['userEmail'] != null) {
        if(!filter_var($_POST['userEmail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $inc++;$_SESSION['error'][$inc] = "INVALID EMAIL";
        }
    }
    function inputs() {
        $_SESSION['values']['fullName'] = $_POST['fullName'];
        $_SESSION['values']['userEmail'] = $_POST['userEmail'];
        $_SESSION['values']['userContact'] = $_POST['userContact'];
        $_SESSION['values']['userMessage'] = $_POST['userMessage'];
        header("location:".SLASHES."career/");
    }
    if($inc > -1) inputs();
    else {
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $mailBody = 
            "message";
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'grimlock.secure-dns.net';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'username';
        $mail->Password = 'password';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->setFrom('jesadiyadivyesh@gmail.com', 'test');
        $mail->addReplyTo('jesadiyadivyesh@gmail.com', 'test');
        $mail->addAddress('jesadiyadivyesh@gmail.com', 'test');
        if($_FILES["cv"]["name"]) $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["cv"]["name"]);
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "test";
        $mail->Body = $mailBody;
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            $_SESSION['error'][0] = "error in sending your data";
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['message'] = "your data send successfully";
        }
        header("location:".SLASHES."career/");
    }
} else header("location:".SLASHES."career/");
```

?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set an attachment header (enctype). 
Add to your form tag:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

And it should be like:

```
<form action="career.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal companyInquiry">
```